# WebRequest follow redirect

Tags: c#, redirect, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a page (url a) which submits a form programmatically using a WebRequest.
The page that accepts the form request does a bunch of stuff and then redirects to another page (url b)

Is it possible at all to perform the webrequest (which reads, processes and redirects the form request), which then makes the current page (url a) redirect to the webrequest end location (url b).

I currently have;

```
  HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url + postVars);  
  myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

  HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();  
  myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

  // Read response stream
  StreamReader myStream = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream());  
  string response = myStream.ReadToEnd();  
  myResponse.Close();
```

This all works fine and everything happens as expected apart from after the `myResponse.Close()`, I am still at url a, not url b, i.e the page that the request was made from is still the active page

Any ideas on where I am going wrong? Or any better ideas?

I need to be able to.

- Open page a
- submit a form programmatically to module b (another page)
- Be redirected to page c (of which is based on the redirect from module b)

Does that make sense?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AllowAutoRedirect` is `true` by default, it doesn't really add anything in your example. And what do you mean by "I am still at URL A not URL B" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confused about how redirects work - you make a *request* to **Url A**, but may ultimately receive a *response* from **Url B** if you get redirected there (and `AllowAutoRedirect` is set to true).

The client / requestor does not get redirected in any shape or form, just *where the response to a client's request is coming from* is. So your "active page" of course never changes.

Comment: Yeah the question was more if a redirect from a webrequest would propagate through to the calling page, which by the sounds of it,  will not. thanks.