# vb.net Post login data httpwebrequest and cookies

Tags: vb.net

im currently trying to login to my website, this works however it wont redirect when it logs in. here is my code

```
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.jamiehayles.com/test/login.php")
        request.Method = "POST"

        Dim postData As String = "username=testing&password=lmao1234"
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        RichTextBox1.Text = responseFromServer
       reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()
```

my question is, do i need cookies for it to redirect? and if so any help guys?

Comment: Define "it won't redirect."  What won't?  Where are you performing or handling a redirect?

Comment: sorry, if i login via a browser it will redirect to "/account.php" however when i login via the app it logs in, however it stays on login.php and wont redirect to accounts.php

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260736/webrequest-follow-redirect

Comment: @user1757913: Right, but in this code you're not handling a redirect in any way.  When a browser receives a redirect response, it sends a new request to the redirected resource.  When this code receives a response, it just reads it and puts it in a text box.

Comment: thanks, this is what i was needing help on also.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what you're doing with the response from the server:

```
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
RichTextBox1.Text = responseFromServer
```

All you're doing is reading it and placing the content of the response into a text box.  You're not actually responding to a redirect in any way.

A "redirect" means that the server responds with a specific [status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and [header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) in the response.  The status code tells the browser that the response is an instruction to redirect to another resource.  The header contains the new resource that the browser should request.

A web browser checks the response for this code/header and performs a new request.  Your code doesn't.  It just shows the response to the user, regardless of what it is.

So, to illustrate, a normal redirect happens like this:

- Browser: I'm requesting this resource.
- Server: Ok, I've received your request, but the resource you really want is actually over there.
- Browser: Ok, then I'm now requesting that resource over there.
- Server: Ok, here you go.

Your code, however, is more like this:

- Code: I'm requesting this resource.
- Server: Ok, I've received your request, but the resource you really want is actually over there.
- Code: [no further action is taken]

The server instructed your code, in an HTTP-standard way, to request a new resource.  Your code simply ignored that instruction.

You need to check [the status code of the response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx), as well as [the headers of the response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers.aspx), and make new requests accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your time David, i shall read on it and try again :)